# How to label sides of a square and its diagonal

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made a square and have a diagonal along the middle. I want to label the bottom side, right side, and the diagonal to show the Pythagorean identity. So the sides should be, 1,1, and square root respectively. How would I add this in the code?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0) ;
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- node[below, pos=.5]{1}(4,0) -- node[right, pos=.5]{1}(4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0) ;
    \draw (0,0) -- node[left, pos=.5, sloped, above]{$\sqrt{2}$}(4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I love you bro thank you.

Comment: would you like to accept and upvote the answer if it met the requirement